# How to set width for a dialog box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to set the width of a dialog box. For that I used the below code

```
$('#splashIndex').click(function() {
    alert('aa');
    $('#terms').dialog("option", "width", 460);
});
```

But its not working. How can I set the width?

Comment: My car is broken, not working. What to do?

Comment: @roasted - the OP's code does do what [the documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-width) says to do to set the width (assuming they're using _that_ dialog plugin), so the question isn't as bad as it seems at first glance.

Comment: @roasted post here.....`:)`

Comment: @jay well, is a picture enough?

Comment: Okay! that would also be fine...`:)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

 $(document).on('click','#splashIndex',function() {
  alert('aa');
  $("#terms").dialog("option", "width", 460);      
 });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are not waiting for DOM ready, maybe your dialog is an dynamic added element. Try using delegation, works in both case:

```
$(document).on('click','#splashIndex', function () {
            alert('aa');
            $('#terms').dialog("option", "width", 460);
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$("#dialogDiv").css("width", 460);
```